# How can I use Bcrypt?

Tags: vb.net, encryption, bcrypt

How can I use BCRYPT in Visual Basic .NET?

Can someone give me a step by step procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Include the [Bcrypt Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt.Net-Next/) in your project.

```vbnet
Dim password = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword("value")
```

Comment: thank you sir how about decryption?

Comment: Bcrypt is generally implemented as a one-way hashing function. You cannot decrypt it.